# shinydashboardPlus' carousel - Chevrons do not appear

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Here's the most basic 3 slide carousel implemented using `shinydashboardPlus`
The default behaviour is to show the previous/next slide chevrons. However, I can't seem to get them to appear. Why is this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Carousel Demo"),

  carousel(indicators = TRUE,
    id = "mycarousel",
    carouselItem(
      tags$img(src = "https://placehold.it/900x500/3c8dbc/ffffff&text=Slide+1")
    ),
    carouselItem(
      tags$img(src = "https://placehold.it/900x500/bbbbbb/ffffff&text=Slide+2")
    ),
    carouselItem(
      tags$img(src = "https://placehold.it/900x500/ff0000/ffffff&text=Slide+3")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have to use `caroussel` from within a `dashboardPagePlus` to get its default layout.

Set `disable = TRUE` to hide the header, and `width = 0` to hide the sidebar, if you don't need them:

```
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus( disable = TRUE ),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar( width = 0 ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    carousel(indicators = TRUE,
             id = "mycarousel",
             carouselItem(
               tags$img(src = "https://placehold.it/900x500/3c8dbc/ffffff&text=Slide+1")
             ),
             carouselItem(
               tags$img(src = "https://placehold.it/900x500/bbbbbb/ffffff&text=Slide+2")
             ),
             carouselItem(
               tags$img(src = "https://placehold.it/900x500/ff0000/ffffff&text=Slide+3")
             )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: What do I do if I want to have a carousel with NONE of the dashboard elements? Just slides, chevrons, and bullets.